# Equilibrium Weighted Graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, osmnx

Is there an algorithm to change certain direction in a multidigraph so that its weight distribute uniformly? I know that we can change direction in multidigraph by removing or adding edges, but I don't know which edge that I should change

```
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west, network_type = 'drive',simplify=True)

for u,v,data in G.edges(data=True):
  data['weight'] = SomeComputation()

ev = [data['weight'] for _,_,data in G.edges(data=True)]

r = plt.boxplot(ev)
```

Here is the result of the
[boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Xp5.png). But there are too many outliers, at least I want the distribution doesn't have that many outlier by adding or removing edges from my graph.

This is how I add or remove edges

```
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G)

oneway = edges[edges.oneway == True]
twoway = edges[edges.oneway == False]

def add_edge(gdf,u,v):
  gdf_copy = gdf
  index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(u,v,0)], names=["u", "v","key"])
  query = gdf_copy.query("u == "+str(v)+" and v == "+str(u))
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=query.values, index=index)
  gdf_copy = gdf_copy.append(df)

  return gdf_copy

def remove_edge(gdf,u,v):
  gdf_copy = gdf
  gdf_copy = gdf_copy[~gdf_copy.isin(gdf_copy.query("u == "+str(u)+" and v == "+str(v)))]
  gdf_copy = gdf_copy[gdf_copy.length.notna()]

  return gdf_copy

list_edge2add = [...] #list of tuple
list_edge2remove = [...] #list of tuple

# applying add_edge() on oneway and remove_edge() on twoway by for looping

gdf = oneway.append(twoway)

# I get new graph
G = ox.graph_from_gdfs(nodes,gdf)

for u,v,data in G.edges(data=True):
  data['weight'] = SomeComputation()

ev = [data['weight'] for _,_,data in G.edges(data=True)]

r = plt.boxplot(ev)
```

The problem is I don't know what list_edge2add and list_edge2remove should I use in order to get a more uniform distribution

Comment: Could you provide a complete minimal reproducible code example of what you've got so far?

Comment: @gboeing I've added my code sample of what I've got so far